# Getting error when trying to write scanned text data into Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an OCR android project that runs on Android Studio. When running the project, the phone opens, and asks user to take picture or select photo from gallery. After selecting the photo, thanks to crop libraries, I am cropping the photo to get desired words from the image. And when clicking detect text button on phone, it gets the word and prints on the screen. The main point is to use Firebase solution to hold detected words on database. I succesfully connected my app into Firebase  Realtime Database. But the words are not written on db.

My mainActivity.java file is below;

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.OAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.OAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;



    private void getTextFromImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();


        if (!recognizer.isOperational()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occurred!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlockSparseArray = recognizer.detect(frame);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < textBlockSparseArray.size(); i++) {
                textBlock = textBlockSparseArray.valueAt(i);
                stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue());
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                //System.out.println("yazı:"+textBlock.getValue());
            }
            textView_data.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            String uid = textBlock.getValue();
            System.out.println("okutulan yazı 2: "+uid);
            ReadWriteUserDetails writeUserDetails = new ReadWriteUserDetails(uid);
            DatabaseReference referenceProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cropped all texts");
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                referenceProfile = referenceProfile.child(firebaseUser.getUid());
            }
            System.out.println("hata verdi 2");

            referenceProfile.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(writeUserDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is written on the database successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


            button_capture.setText("Retake");
            button_copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }




}
```

All codes related with database connection is under the getTextFromImage method. Therefore, it is better to focus inside the method, I think that there is a problem on referenceProblem or getUid(). There is no error on detecting text, the problem is to write detected text into database. Realtime Database connection is already done. When trying to run the app, taking the photo, cropping and detecting text on phone screen are all OK.

Here is the error I am getting on console;

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28303
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=203, result=-1, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4520)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.getTextFromImage(MainActivity.java:144)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I also tried to check nullability of the object. It would be really good, if you can help.

Comment: This means that there is no current user somewhere in your code, and you're calling `getUid()` on a `null` value. This is not a syntactic problem, but rather a problem with how/when you determine the current user. Have a look at the questions I linked to learn how to troubleshoot this type of error.

Comment: Thank you for your responding, actually I have no functionality about login or register. I want to store my detected text into realtime database. What could your suggest me. Where is my error on getTextFromImage method?

Comment: As said, there is no current user in your code - so you can't get the UID of the current user (which is what `firebaseUser.getUid()` tries to do). If you want to write to the database under the current user's UID you'll need a current user. If you don't want to require a current user, remove all code that needs that and write somewhere in the database that doesn't require a current user.